# Can I delay loading of some controls on an xPage to after page loaded

Tags: ajax, delay, lotus-domino, xpages

is it possible to delay loading of some controls on an xpage?

This is the problem: let's say you have a control that does a fultextsearch and displays the result in a repeat control. this ft search might take a long time and will hold the webpage loading in a waiting state until the search result is ready.

I want my page to load most of the data initally, and some "time consuming" controls should be loaded in to the page as a sperate request after the inital load.

this way the user will immediatly see the webpage, but some of the data on the page will load a little bit later without holding the webpage in a waiting state from the server.

possible?

Answer (score 6):

The downside to using rendered is that all the value bindings will still evaluate, even if the corresponding markup isn't sent to the page. So the trick here is making sure the components don't even exist until you want them to.

Every component has a getChildren() method. This returns a mutable List of components, which has a add() method. This allows you to add components to the page on the fly, either while the page is loading, or later during an event. For the purposes of what you're trying to do, you would want to defer adding the "expensive" components until a subsequent event.

Create an event handler attached directly to the view root (), give it a unique ID (e.g. "loadExpensiveComponentsEvent", set its refresh mode to partial, set a refresh ID to whatever div or panel will contain the search results, and set its event name to an arbitrary event (e.g. "loadExpensiveComponents"). This prevents your event from being triggered by actual user behavior. Set the event's code to SSJS that will inject your components.

Then add a script block () to trigger the event after the page has loaded:

XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
XSP.firePartial(null, "#{id:loadExpensiveComponentsEvent}");
});

Your page will load without the search result components. Once the page has fully loaded, it will trigger the component injection event automatically.

For guidance on how to code the injection event, open the Java file that has been generated from your existing page to see what components need to be injected and what to set their values to.

Answer (score 2):

You can pack them into a panel and set their rendered status to rendered=#{viewScope.pageFullyLoaded}. Then in the onLoad event have a XSP. partialRefresh request where you set viewScope.pageFullyLoaded=true
A little ugly but doable. Now you can wrap that code into your own custom control, so you could have a "lazyGrid", "lazyPanel" etc.

Comment: do you mean I use client side js for the partialrefresh and server side js for setting the viewscope?

Comment: That's why you need to wrap it in a rendered one

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I did not think of this before. the dynamic content control in extlib actually solves this problem. the dcc can be triggered onClientLoad both using javascript and ssjs afer the page has loaded.

one problem I am facing now is that I am already using the dcc on my site so I need to put another dcc within my dcc. and this seem to be a bit buggy. I have reported it to the extlib team on openNTF.